# Signalr push notification only to the caller in load balancing environment

Tags: signalr

I am new to SignalR. In my scenario I want to push back the notification only to the caller. In a normal client-server communication this happens in a straight forward manner i.e client talks to server using hub proxy. However if there is a load balancer in between the client and server I am unable to imagine the scenario.

Lets say client sends a request and load balancer directs it to one of the server.The connection between the client and server is lost at this point. If the server processes the request further and after some time it detects that it has to push back the notification back to the caller. When the server sends the push back notification to the load balancer with a newly established connection, it doesn't know to which client it has to return the data as it doesn't store any state of the client.

Is this understanding is correct? If this is correct, how do we maintain the state of client and server in order to send the push back notification to the corresponding caller?

I have gone through the 'Backplane' concept of SignalR and my understanding is that this feature is helpful in broadcasting scenario. However I want to send the data back only to the caller. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you  tried `context.clients.caller.broadcasting`

Comment: Hi Joker, thanks for the response. the above code will return the data back to only caller. However the load balancer sitting in between client and server creates the problem. Load balancer doesn't know to which client it has to send the data back.

Answer (score -1):

it can be load balancer sticky session problem.